# How pass preprocessed data between 2 routes in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating an multipage app where in the first page (/index) user selects needed parameters in a form, then they are sent to server (I'm using Flask framework)
and the parameters are used to do some calculations on a data and the results are returned to new route that visualizes the data using D3.js (/res?par1=2&par2=3). The route is just an easier example. Now on the picture I want to click on a part (that represents a sub-part of data) and redirect to new route: /res?par1=2&par2=3&**sub="sub1"**.

EDIT: 
My simplified example of routes is like this:

```
@app.route('/<ds>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def treeview(ds):
    distMeasure = request.args.get('dist')
    correction = request.args.get('corr')
    big_json_tree = tree2json(distMeasure, correction, cutStrategy, minSize,   maxSize, ..)

    if request.args.get('node_id'):
        id = request.args.get('node_id')
        select_data = select(big_json_tree,id)
        render_template("nodeview.html", data=select_data)
    else:
        render_template("baseview.html", data=big_json_tree)
```

So it works like that: I go to nodeview page with url /ds?dist=p&corr=a (there are more parameters) and there is a tree. If I click on a tree node, then I should be redirected to new page /ds?dist=p&corr=a&node_id=2 where I have a subdata from big_json_data and I plot it.

My problem is, that if I go to new route I need some data from initial route, but the calculations take time so I want to keep the calculated objects and use them in "children"-route. I also want to move back and forward on these pages and not to do the initial calculations all the time.

I know about the session, but it seems that it's not meant for complicated objects.

Any ideas how to solve this kind of routing? (Either in Flask routes or browser side)

Comment: I would try to keep the routing as simple as possible, and use a [cache](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/caching/) to temporarily store the calculated results.

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do that server side  would be to use CBV's aka: Class Based Views, (in flask that means using `flask.views.View` or `flask.views.MethodView` as the base view class) and save the data as a class level variable, then any processing functions that need to share the data just need to be implemented as methods of the view. example:

```
import flask
from flask import views

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config.SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

class IndexView(MethodView):
    _some_processing_var = 100
    _another_var = 2

    def get(self,arg=None):
        if arg is None:
            IndexView._some_processing_var = 55
        else:
            IndexView._another_var = arg
        return flask.jsonify(result=IndexView._another_var*IndexView._some_processing_var)

app.add_url_rule('/','index',view_func=IndexView.as_view('index'))
app.add_url_rule('/<arg>','arg_index',view_func=IndexView.as_view('arg_index'))
```

something like that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't fully understand how this would work in my case.
I'll add my example:)